# How to detect the newline character with gzgetc in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, file-io, zlib

I want to read an entire line of a file character by character using gzgetc and stop when the newline is encountered.  I know there is a function to grab the entire line but I would like to try to do it this way first.  I tried:

```
Int c;

do {
  c = gzgetc((gzFile) fp);
  cout << c;
} while (c != '\n');
```

The result was an infinite loop.  I tried adding (char) before c, still the same result.  What am I doing wrong?  The data file I am trying to read is encoded in base64 and I want to read in each token separated by space. Some of the lines are variable length and have a mixture of encoded and not encoded data which I set up an algorithm for I just need to know how to stop at newline.

Comment: What is `fp`...?

Comment: the file descriptor

Comment: how did you get one?

Comment: Please create a [MCVE].

Comment: Shouldn't `fp` be a `gzFile` (returned by `gzopen`) already? Why do you need to cast it? Note that `gzgetc` returns -1 on error or end of file, so you should check for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also check for `gzgetc()` returning `-1`, which indicates an error or end of file, and exiting the loop in that case. Your infinite loop is likely due to one of those.